# Extension buttons in Google Chrome no longer respond to left-clicking

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I tried right-clicking each one of the extension buttons for Google Chrome and they no longer respond to right-clicking, and do not show the usual menu.

I am running Google Chrome on Ubuntu. What is the most likely cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing and then readding the extentions?

Comment: I tried disabling and then enabling all the extensions, and this temporarily fixed the problem. The problem appears again whenever I restart Chrome.

Comment: Clicking the "remove from Chrome" button has no effect whatsoever, and this problem appears to affect Windows as well as Linux. I can only hope that the Chromium team is aware of this issue, and is planning to fix it.